# delphi 7 convert HTTP gets to HTTPS gets

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a program that currently uses Delphi 7 with Indy 9 (I believe) that performs several HTTP `GET` requests.  I need to convert them to use HTTPS now.

The server side is under my control.

I also do not want to install any external DLLs with my program.

I have done many Google searches, but to me it appears I either have to install the external OpenSSL DLLs, or upgrade to a later Delphi version, or use a 3rd party control that is not as simple as the `TIdHTTP` component.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Indy 9 requires OpenSSL DLLs for SSL/TLS, and even then it requires *custom-built* versions of the DLLs.  Those DLLs are available on Indy's [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com) in the `/SSL/Archive` folder.

To use HTTPS in `TIdHTTP` in Indy 9, simply assign Indy's `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, and then deploy the custom OpenSSL DLLs with your app.  But note that the DLLs are very old (as is Indy 9 in general), so you will not be able to use modern security protocols beyond TLS 1.0.

Indy 10, on the other hand, does not require OpenSSL *specifically*.  OpenSSL is Indy's *default* SSL/TLS engine, but you can plugin another SSL/TLS engine by writing/obtaining a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived wrapper component for it.  Some 3rd party SSL/TLS engines provide such an `SSLIOHandler`, such as [Eldos SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/), and there may be other 3rd party `SSLIOHandler` implementations floating around as well.

In theory, Indy 10 does support Delphi versions back to 5 (though older versions are not regularly tested), so you should be able to update your Delphi 7 app to use Indy 10.

To use HTTPS in `TIdHTTP` in Indy 10, simply assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, and then deploy the DLLs (if any) with your app.

Indy 10's `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component uses standard OpenSSL DLLs, not custom DLLs, so you can use any OpenSSL DLL distribution (there are up-to-date DLLs provided in the Fulgan mirror in the `/SSL` folder).

If you are adamant about avoiding DLLs, and you don't want to pay a lot of money for a 3rd party SSL/TLS engine, you could at least write your own custom `SSLIOHandler` that wraps Microsoft's [SChannel API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx), which is built-in to Windows and does not rely on distributable DLLs (an SChannel-based `SSLIOHandler` implementation is expected to be included in a future version of Indy).